# Accumulate sum one to previous record until it reach index value to 0

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I would like to create another column which if it is zero, then the index is zero, and add one from it per row until it reaches to zero again

for example, i have a data-set

```
index value
 1     10 
 2     10
 3     10
 0     10
 5     10
 6     10
 8     10
 0     10
 2     10
 4     10
```

What i expect the new index is that

```
index   value  new Index
  1     10       1 
  2     10       2
  3     10       3
  0     10       0 
  5     10       1
  6     10       2 
  8     10       3
  0     10       0
  2     10       1
  4     10       2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
mask = df['index'].ne(0)

df['new Index'] = (mask.cumsum() - mask.cumsum().where(~mask).ffill().fillna(0)).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 1):

My working;Combine `.cumsum(), .cumcount()`

Data

```
 index  value
0   1       10
1   2       10
2   3       10
3   0       10
4   5       10
5   6       10
6   8       10
7   0       10
8   2       10
9   4       10
```

Working

```
df['group']=df['index'].eq(0).cumsum()#Create groups
df['new-index']=df.groupby('group').cumcount()+1#Calculate new index
```

Chained solution

```
df['new-index']=(df.assign(group=df['index'].eq(0).cumsum())).groupby('group').cumcount()+1
```

Result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:-

```
x = [1,2,3,0,5,6,8,0,2,4]
y = [10 for i in range(len(x))]
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(x, y)), 
               columns =['index', 'value'])
index = df["index"]
new_index = list()
flag = False
i=0
for val in index:
    if val == 0:
        i = 0
        flag= True
    if flag == False:
        new_index.append(val)
        continue
    new_index.append(i)
    i+=1
df["new Index"] = new_index
df
```

It should give you output

```
value   index   new Index
0   10  1   1
1   10  2   2
2   10  3   3
3   10  0   0
4   10  5   1
5   10  6   2
6   10  8   3
7   10  0   0
8   10  2   1
9   10  4   2
```